# Аналог set в django tamplate для выводы данных в html-таблицу

Tags: python, html, django, jinja

Есть таблица ячеек расписания. Каждая ячейка содержит кнопку "Добавить", если не будет соответствующих дню недели и номеру урока данных из бд, иначе будет кнопка "Изменить". Я использую обычный template django, из-за чего у меня нет возможности использовать set для установки флажка, как представлено ниже. Пытался что-то придумать с with, forloop.counter, но не вышло. Как настроить функционал кнопки "Добавить" в таком случае?

`html`:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Часы</th>
        <th>Понедельник</th>
        <th>Вторник</th>
        <th>Среда</th>
        <th>Четверг</th>
        <th>Пятница</th>
        <th>Суббота</th>
    </tr>
{% for hour in hours %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ hour }}</td>
    {% for day in days %}
    <td>
    {% set flag = 0 %}
        <a href="{% url 'data-new' %}?day={{ day }}&pair={{ hour }}&student_group.id=12321"><button>Добавить</button></a>
        {% for cell in cells %}
            {% if cell.day == day and cell.pair.number == hour and cell.student_group.id == 12321 %}
                {{ cell.pair }}<br>
                {{ cell.day }}
                {{ cell.subject_code }}<br>
                {{ cell.student_group }}<br>
                {{ cell.room }}<br>
                {{ cell.teacher_pk }}
                <a href="{% url 'data-update' cell.id %}"><button>Изменить</button></a>
                {% set flag = 1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if flag == 0 %}
        <a href="{% url 'data-new' %}?day={{ day }}&pair={{ hour }}&student_group.id=12321"><button>Добавить</button></a>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

`views.py`:

```
def admin_table(request):
    cells = Cell.objects.all()
    days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    hours = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    context = {'cells': cells, 'days': days, 'hours': hours}
    return render(request, 'main/admin_table.html', context)
```